# Hash table of templated functor

Tags: c++11, hashtable, functor

I want to create a hastable to member templated functor, I explain.
Here is my exemple which does'nt work:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
class MyFirstClass
{
    int i_;

public:
    MyFirstClass(): i_(0) {}

    void setI(int i) { i_ = i; }
    int getI() { return i_; }
};

class MySecondClass
{
    bool b_;

public:

    MySecondClass(): b_(0) {}

    void setB(bool b) { b_ = b; }
    bool getB() { return b_; }
};

template<class X, void (X::*p)()>
class MyFunctor
{
    X& _x;
public:
    MyFunctor(X& x) : _x( x ) {}
    void operator()() const { (_x.*p)(); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unordered_map<string,MyFunctor> myHashTable;

    MyFirstClass first;
    MyFirstClass second;

    myHashTable["int"] = first::setI;
    myHashTable["bool"] = second::setB;

    //
    string key = "bool";
    int value = 1;

    myHashTable[key](value);

    return 0;
}
```

I have multiple class with their own setter . I would like to be able thanks to the has table and a command {string,int} change the value of the corresponding class.

The previous code is not working for the moment and I am stuck.

Comment: In `myHashTable[key](value);`, how will you know what type `value` is supposed to have?

Comment: I don't know, it could be a int a double or a bool. I think it will be impossible with a hastable but could it be done with a table of functor?

Comment: What should happen if you make a mistake and try to call, for example, `setB` with `15`? (in fact, that's pretty much what you did in your example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, as it stands.

Firstly, from your example `unordered_map<string,MyFunctor>` doesn't name a type, because `MyFunctor` doesn't name a type. You could create a non-template base class with a virtual `operator()`, and then have MyFunctor inherit from it.

Second, you aren't using compatible method pointers, `MyFirstClass::setI` and `MySecondClass::setB` both take a parameter.

Third, related to the first, you have to specify the template parameters when constructing an object from a class template. (until c++17's class template deduction guides). You also have ungrammatical syntax that I assume is trying to specify the object argument to the `MyFunctor` constructor alongside the method-pointer template argument.

You would have something like

```
class MyFunctorBase {
    virtual void operator()(void * i) const = 0;
}

template<class T, class X, void (X::*p)(T)>
class MyFunctor : public MyFunctorBase 
{
    X& _x;
public:
    MyFunctor(X& x) : _x( x ) {}
    void operator()(void * i) const override { (_x.*p)(*static_cast<T*>(i)); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unordered_map<string,shared_ptr<MyFunctorBase>> myHashTable;

    MyFirstClass first;
    MyFirstClass second;

    myHashTable["int"] = make_shared<MyFunctor<int, MyFirstClass, &MyFirstClass::setI>>(first);
    myHashTable["bool"] = make_shared<MyFunctor<bool, MySecondClass, &MySecondClass::setB>>(second);


    //
    string key = "bool";
    bool value = true;

    (*myHashTable[key])(static_cast<void *>(&value));

    return 0;
}
```

Or, much more easily, use the existing [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), which does that for you

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unordered_map<string,function<void(void *)>> myHashTable;

    MyFirstClass first;
    MyFirstClass second;

    myHashTable["int"] = [first](void * i) { first.setI(*static_cast<int *>(i)); };
    myHashTable["bool"] = [second](void * i) { second.setB(*static_cast<bool *>(i)); };


    //
    string key = "bool";
    bool value = true;

    myHashTable[key](static_cast<void *>(&value));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it. Is it possible to declare the Functor like this : template<typename T,class X, void (X::*p)(T)> class MyFunctor : public MyFunctorBase . For the double and float type.

Comment: You could use [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/any.html) as your parameter type and unwrap it in the template, yes

Comment: So you can have a commun functor for double int float and bool?

Comment: See edits. Note that `boost::any_cast` throws at runtime, rather than fails to compile, if the types don't match

Comment: Thank you. I try to install boost on windows but there are troubles for the moment. I saw there is any equivalent in c++17 but in Qt I cannot set c++17.

Comment: Yes, that using void* as the intermediary type would also work, but then the failure mode is undefined behaviour, rather than a specific exception

Comment: I get a strange error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\memory:901: error: C2259: 'MyFunctor<int,MyFirstClass,void MyFirstClass::setI(int)>': cannot instantiate abstract class

Comment: Ah, my mistake, there is `const` on the derived but not on the base.

Comment: It works for my only with that     (*myHashTable[key])(static_cast<void *>(&value)); . I think you forget the * in your first example.

Comment: Oh yes. I still think std::function is more useful here